# How to delete an array of char* in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor

I looked around the web for this but I did not find an answer. If my class has a protected member declared as such: `char * arr[3] = {"Blah", "Blah", "Blah"}`
Would I need to delete this member in the destructor? If so, what is the correct syntax? Thank you!

Comment: You only need to `delete` if you use `new`. So no. This is an array literal that can be stored on the stack.

Comment: @PaulRooney what is a way that I could declare this method as dynamic? Would it be `char ** arr = new char*[3];` ?

Comment: Use std::string for strings. Your compiler should complain about a missing const.

Comment: @manni66 I can’t use the string class, it’s a programming assignment and they want all strings to be stored as char*

Comment: A pointer to a string constant has to be `const char*`.

Comment: @AdrianBernat -- *It’s a programming assignment and they want all strings to be stored as char* * -- That shouldn't stop you from creating a home-made simple string class, so as to thwart these restrictions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The time required to do this is IMO prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

> > Would I need to delete this member in the destructor?

No.

And of course:

> > I can’t use the string class, it’s a programming assignment and they want all strings to be stored as char*

This is a quite silly restriction in a C++ assignment.